# Queueing signals on OS X

Tags: macos, unix, signals

As far as I have been able to determine, real time signals are not supported in OS X.

I'd like to know whether it's possible for signals to queue in OS X.

For example, if I send SIGUSR2 to an application 10 times in quick sucession, am I guaranteed to get 10 calls to the signal handler or is it possible that some of them will be discarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signals can be discarded. The pending signals for a process are recorded in a bitmask. If the same signal arrives multiple times before the process can handle it (including because that signal is blocked, including because the process is currently handling that signal), then it will just set a bit in the mask that's already set. There's no queue. There's no count.

Search for `_siglist` (substring of both `uu_siglist` and `p_siglist`, one for threads the other for processes) in the [kernel source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/kern/kern_sig.c).